# Is There a way to know if the database is empty?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im Working with SQLiteDatabase and i want to create only 1 row on the database, so i wana use if statement for this, my question is if there is a way to know if the database is empty or not.
Thank you!

Comment: do you mean database or Table??

Comment: a thing is the database, another is a table. Maybe you mean if the table is empty?

Comment: `select count(*) from my_table;`?

Comment: yeah if the table is empty, sorry my bas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I'll update my answer to help you a little bit further.

If you want to find out if the **table exists** and if it **has rows**:

```
Cursor query = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'table1'", null);
if (query.moveToFirst()) {
    // If that table exists, check if it has any rows
    query = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM table1", null);
    if (query.moveToFirst()) {
        // Table exists and it has rows. Do something with them here.
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to change the 'table' and 'android_metadata' and 'sqlite_sequence' to something? or the type and name? or just copy this jsut the way it is?

Comment: No you do not. But since you said that you need to check table rows,  use the second code block, not the first one.

Comment: so the statemnt query.moveToFirst() will return true when there are rows in the table and false when there are none?

Comment: Yes. And `query.getInt(0);` will return the amount of rows inside a table. If you will get the count though remember to use it after `if (moveToFirst())`.

Comment: and if i got no table, the code wont work? but i create the table on the onCreate() Method of the SQLiteOpenHelper right?

Comment: You need to know the name of the table that exists for the code to work. You are diving into *other questions* now. If this question was answered select the correct answer and ask another question.